# Cannot create SQL Connector in Azure

Tags: sql, azure

I'm creating a new MS SQL Connector to Azure database. Following the guide at: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-connector-sql

As a result the connector is not created due to missing 'LOCATION' input.
How can I specify this property? Does that depend on Azure Subscription used?

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Location is in reference to which data region you want your connector to reside.  Is this connector in US East, US East 2, Central US etc.

The view you are seeing in the tutorial leverages the new Azure Portal, the Location will reside within the App Service Plan configuration settings.

Comment: An App Service Plan is selected by default with associated Location. Mine still is North Europe. It is now working just fine, must have been a glitch in Azure portal. Still a valid answer though, App Service Plan config is where Location property is set.